# The Schema returned by the new query differs from the base query

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, query-builder

I have developed an application in C# using visual studio. I connected to an SQL server nd used data binding to get data to data grids. the thing is now I want to get data to a Data Grid from two tables. I went on and added a new query to the grid and I cannot set it. it works with the query builder bt cannot set it to the data grid.

```
SELECT        Employee.Eid, Employee.Fname, Employee.DateOfJoin, Employee.EmpType,   EmpSlary.TotSalary
FROM          EmpSlary INNER JOIN
                     Employee ON EmpSlary.EmpID = Employee.Eid
```

above is the query! can any one point me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without including both queries but the issue is probably that the fields returned by the queries differ. The fields returned must be the same and be in the same order.